# Get row number from a query in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I've got a table with a large number of rows. When I query all rows, it takes far too long. If it's possible, I was wondering if there was a way to specifically get the row number of a row *when sorted*.

So for example:
    
    `Banana
    Apple
    Pear
    Orange
    ...` is all in a column. If I were to sort this, is there a more efficient way to get Orange's row number?

If needed, some of the work can be done in Java, it doesn't have to be purely SQL. The main thing here is to not search through an entire result for one specific row's number (and hence take longer).

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

Comment: I don't understand - can't you just use integer primary key and query by it?

Comment: "when sorted". A primary key would work, but once sorted it won't represent the actual order.